# $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] differ on localhost and server

Tags: php, user-agent

Why is this happening? I cant determine the version of Firefox in PHP.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

**Firefox**

```
localhost: string(78) 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 <b>Firefox/66.0</b>"

server: string(78) 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 <b>Firefox/CA4C</b>"
```

**Chrome**

```
localhost: string(115) 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 <b>Safari/537.36</b>"

server: string(115) 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 <b>Safari/CA4C4F</b>"
```

Comment: Something in your server's configuration is modifying the user agent.

Comment: Did it add `<b>` around the browser name at the end, or was that your attempt to highlight the difference?

Comment: <b> was an attempt to highlight the difference